# Android Plot Domain Format: Decimal Value

Tags: android

I'm trying to plot some points in an AndroidPlot where the x_value has 3 significant value after the comma. How can I show all the points as separated from each other? Actually the step on the x domain is too big so I can see only point one over other.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yes,thank you, I just use

```
 mLineChart.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0.000"));
```

for three decimal after the comma

Answer (score 0):

You can set the step value using

```
mLineChart.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 5);
```

You can set the Format using

```
mLineChart.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));
```